# Scroll not working automatically using css

Tags: html, css

Div scroll is not showing automatically.

```css
.sectionContent {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.asideContent {
  flex: none;
  width: 30rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eceff1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.rightSideDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I am having Section inside that having aside and Div. Div scroll not showing automatically and some times showing but div not fully displaying when check in responsive way. here I am providing in section, aside, div css classes, please help.

Comment: Can u plz add the html code?

Comment: Seems to be working, maybe theres no issue with CSS but your HTML? [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/t1qpfsm6/)

Comment: yes, working after changing height: 60vh, but I am not sure its correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

After changing .sectionContent as {height: 60vh} its working , but i am not sure its correct or not.